# Knockout JS access ViewModel defined for partial cshtml page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have post and like/unlike on post. For like/unlike I have created partial. The post is main page where I am rendering partial LikeUnline page.

I want to keep two viewmodels:

1. PostViewModel which is working fine with binding.
2. LikeUnlikeViewModel which is creating problem when I am trying to access it on link click.

Following is my code

```
<button id="alike" data-bind='click: LikeViewModel.Like' >Like</button>
<button id ="aUnlike" data-bind='click: LikeViewModel.Like'>UnLike</button>
```

I am getting below warning message and my function is not executing.

> event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.

There is alert message which should show if Like function call.

Comment: What does your view model look like?

Comment: A fiddle would really help, but that message is just a warning. I'd bet it has nothing to do with your function not executing.